# Unable to retrive allowance

Tags: solidity

I have a scenario where a user approves an allowance of a standard `erc20` token to a contract address using the `approve` function as follows using the truffle console.

```
TOKEN.approve("contractAddress", 10000000)
```

It generates a `tx` and when I check the allowance using the `allowance` function, I can see the approved allowance as

```
TOKEN.allowance(account[0], "contractAddress")
```

It gives me the correct amount and I can also see the correct tx and data in the transaction.

The issue is when I call the same `allowance` function from inside a contract (where the tokens were sent to), I never get the amount.

The following function in my Contract.

```
function checkUserAllowance() public virtual returns (bool) {
  
 // load contract interface
  IERC20 TOKEN = IERC20("contractAddress"); // I can verify it is the correct address
    
  // check the approved allowance
  uint256 allowance = TOKEN.allowance(msg.sender, address(this));
  require(allowance > 0, "No approved allowance");

  return true;

  }
```

When calling `checkUserAllowance` I always get the "No approved allowance" message and it never goes through. I can confirm that I am sending requests from the correct user.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help someone one day, so if you making a simple call to a function there is a chance that the function is executed before the `msg.sender` is filled. In that case as a workaround and if it is `safe` for your function to have `msg.sender` as an `address` as a parameter such as following

```
function checkUserAllowance(address sender) public virtual returns (bool){..}
```

If it is `unsafe` for your function to receive sender's address as a parameter (highly depends on your requirements) then you need use transaction (instead of just calling the function) which fills the `msg.sender` first before executing the function as transaction means you want to change the state of the blockchain.

for more : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51847788/msg-sender-does-not-work-inside-a-view-function-why-is-there-a-workaround

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps, but:

When instantiating the ERC20 I see

```
 IERC20 TOKEN = IERC20("contractAddress");
```

If you mean here by "contractAddress" the ERC20 address, then it should actually work.

The first "contractAddress" and "toAddress" are the same right?

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes that is correct, both `toAddress` and `contractAddress` are the same and it is a standard `erc20` contract

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct but i think when you calling token contract through your contract, msg.sender of this function is your contract, so this will returns you allowance which both of owner and spender are your contract address.

I hope it helps you because i'm nut sure 100% but it should be work

Comment: thanks @Alireze, afaik msg.sender is the tx sender, I figured it out, I posted the answer here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/142565/114354